# No idea of how to simulate car crashes

Tags: c#, unity

I have a simple car game with all the basic collision detection and movement in Unity with C#. But when I was building the "engine" for the game I didn't include a detail I later decided to include. I want the possibility so that cars can get damaged and so that the model can change. For example the car looked like it was new and after a crash it looks like a wreck. Please help me by pointing to some resources or by telling me approximate ways of implementing this new feature. Thanks!

Comment: Break it down into smaller, manageable pieces (the problem I mean... maybe the car as well). Examine crashes in slow motion and identify the different things that happen throughout the crashing process. These smaller pieces should be easier for you to figure out where to begin and hopefully you can put it all together to make a crash simulation. Or just apply damage and change the car model at different damage thresholds. That could work too...

Comment: Get 0 more upvotes and go into chat now!, this question isn't really properly formatted, it's too broad, too vague, too opinions based, etc -- http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development

Comment: thanks a lot, especially @SpartanDonut. I decided to use the first approach works fine xD